# IIS sending mail

Tags: asp.net, iis, smtp

I have succefully setup my ASP app to be drop the email to a maildrop box designated by the ISS. I can see the email in the folder which I have specified. This is what I have specified in my IIS management settings:

```
E-mail address: administrator@aspdotnet-suresh.com  
Store e-mail in pickup directory: C:\temp\maildrop
```

Will this send an email to my account specified in the app? This is a password reset system and the email document inside the folder has the correct to and from address but I don't know how to install the actual SMTP server and not sure if the IIS Manager will make it happen by dropping it in this folder?

Sorry, I am new to this stuff

Comment: You might have better luck asking your question on ServerFault.com or http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you want the email delivered, you want to use an SMTP relay [of some sort].  Placing it in the maildrop assumes that there is some other protocol which is going to be used to retreive it from that maildrop (ie. POP3).

If you want to talk about how to configure IIS and SMTP, your question will probably get better results on [www.serverfault.com](http://www.serverfault.cm).